# How can I prove that the empty string is the identity element with regards to the operation of concatenation?

Tags: strings, algebra

Let $w$ be a string over an alphabet $\Sigma$. It is obvious that $w \circ \epsilon = \epsilon \circ w = w$.
However I'm having a hard time coming up with a proof for that (which I assume should be fairly easy, I just don't know how to tackle it).

My first thought on how to do it is the following:

$\Sigma^{*}$ is the smallest set that contains $\Sigma$ and is closed under the operation of concatenation.
Thus $(\Sigma^{*},\circ)$ is (at least) a magma.
Now I would need to prove that $(\Sigma^{*},\circ)$ is a monoid.

But I don't know how to take it further from there or if that approach is going to lead anywhere.

I thank you in advance for helping me out.

Comment: $\epsilon\cdot w=w\cdot \epsilon = w$ would be the definition of $\epsilon$. In fact, the smallest set that contains $\Sigma$ and is closed under concatenation is $\Sigma^* \setminus\{\epsilon\}$

Comment: The first step is writing the definitions of all concepts involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to define the set of words and the concatenation operation.

A word over $\Sigma$ is either $\epsilon$ or $\sigma.w$, where $\sigma \in \Sigma$ and $w$ is a word over $\Sigma$. This definition can be formalized in several ways, but what is important here is the induction principle: a property $P$ of words holds for all words over $\Sigma$ if (i) $P(\epsilon)$ and (ii) if $P(w)$ then $P(\sigma.w)$ for all $\sigma \in \Sigma$.

The concatenation $x \circ y$ of two words $x,y$ over $\Sigma$ is defined inductively as follows: $\epsilon \circ y = y$ and $(\sigma.x) \circ y = \sigma.(x \circ y)$.

This definition makes it clear that $\epsilon \circ y = y$. We can prove that $y \circ \epsilon = y$ by induction on $y$. First, $\epsilon \circ \epsilon = \epsilon$. Second, suppose that $y \circ \epsilon = y$. Then $(\sigma.y) \circ \epsilon = \sigma.(y \circ \epsilon) = \sigma.y$.